# Flatten transparent pdf image in linux using command line

Tags: linux, r, graphics, vector-graphics

I'm using R to generate graphics with many transparent layers.  I want the output as a pdf, but filesizes explode when there are so many transparent layers.  I can manually open each one in GIMP and flatten it there, but I'd like to do this via a `system()` call in R, so that the process can be automated.  Does anybody know of a way to do this?

Here is a silly reproducible example:

```
set.seed(2)
x = sort(runif(100))*10
y = rgamma(100,shape = x*rexp(100),scale=1/exp(rnorm(100)))
plot(x,y)
for (i in 1:200){
y = rgamma(100,shape = x*rexp(100),scale=1/exp(rnorm(100)))
fit = loess(y~x)
points(x,y,col=rgb(0,1,0,.3))
lines(x,predict(fit),col=rgb(1,0,0,.3))
}
```

Now, I want to be able to do `dev.copy2pdf(file="dumb_graph.pdf")`, and then do `system(something)` to flatten the image.  Or most likely, a number of different system calls.  Does anyone know of any utilities that will do this?

Edit:  I'm looking for linux-specific solutions, but I guess that solutions on other platforms would be useful posts for others who may search for this one day.

Edit2:  the output should be vector.

Comment: consider using `imageMagick`, on the command line, it can be used via `convert ...` for manipulating all kinds of graphics files...

Comment: That sort of works!  `convert dumb_graph.pdf -flatten flat_graph.pdf`.  Only problem is that the resolution gets pretty bad...

Comment: Edit:  and it is no longer a vector image.

Comment: so you have a new question :)

Comment: I want to flatten the image but keep it vector!  :)  Like in GIMP.

Comment: hehe, would like to help, but I can't. It's worth Stackexchange Question was what I meant, but probably not `SO`, but `super user` or something similar